# Adding text to fix within a polygon (path) in SVG

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg, snap.svg

I have a polygon created using Snap.svg as so:

```
var polygon = s.polyline(200, 286, 250, 200, 350, 200, 400, 286, 350, 373, 250, 373).attr('fill', 'green');
```

I also have text like so:

```
var t = s.text(300, 286, "snap");
```

How do I make the text (if it was long) wrap and stay within the polygon? Also does Snap.svg support html inside a shape? Thanks.

Comment: SVG does not support this directly, you'd have to split the text into paragraphs yourself.

Comment: Yeah that's what I've been reading so far too.

Comment: You could create a foreignObject element and then wrap html text within that.

Comment: Yeah but I need to support IE 10 (yikes) and I think it only works in IE 11+. IE just really sucks.

Comment: I don't think IE 11 supports foreignObject